# displaying part of an image with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image

I am doing a visualization, and the calculations can return with fractions (e.g. 23.43, 4.3, 39.79,...). I need to show icons for every integer in the result (e.g. 23 -> 23 icons, 4--> 4 icons, 39 --> 39 icons).

Now it should also break the icons of the fraction part, maybe in decimals, but possibly down to quarters. E.g. 23.43 --> 23 icons and 0.4 (or 0.5 if quarters) of the horizontal part of the icon, 4.3 --> 4 icons and 0.3 (or 0.25) of the x part of the icon, 39.79 --> 39 icons and 0.8 (or 0.75) of the x part of the icon, and so on.

How could I do this? I saw some approaches with using backgrounds with css, but that doesn't look to be exactly what I need. I'd prefer some jquery way of doing it.

EDIT: here an image of what I am trying to do

[image]

Comment: Since you are doing visualization, could you please also visualize your question, i.e. add some pictures to it? Not quite clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally set this image to be a `background-image` of a `<div>`, and set `width` to a multiple of the image's width (eg. 23.4 * width) and `background-repeat` to `repeat-x`.

If you specifically refuse the usage of background, then set the `overflow` to `hidden` and use a `loop` in JS to `document.createElement` a specified number of `image`s inside the `div`. This way, the last one can be a 'half-visible' thanks to the overflow.

**Edit:**

In order to solve this, you need to set a line break. For example, seeing that your image is 21px wide, let's say that the maximum number of images in one line is 20 (840px wide).

Let's say then, that you need to place 75.5 images.

First, you create a `div` with the width of 840px and put `75.5 - (75.5 % 20)` images there. It should create three rows of images. You then put the rest (`75.5 % 20 = 15.5 => 16 images`) in a new `div` with the width of `15.5 * 21` px and overflow hidden like in the previous case. Again, the last 16th image will be half visible.

**Edit 2:**

If the width of the images varies, there can be a new technique: Use only one `div` with fixed width to anything you like. Put all images into it. Add a new `div` after the last `image` with opaque background in the colour of the your pages's:

http://jsfiddle.net/qTb8T/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="overlay">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
     background: blue;
    width: 700px;
}
#overlay {
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
}
```

**JS:**

```
var count = 75.5,
    ceil = Math.ceil(count),
    image = 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png',
    overlay = $('#overlay'),
    wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
    hide = ceil - count;

for(var i = 0; i < ceil; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = image;
    wrapper.prepend(img);
}

overlay.css({
    'width': img.clientWidth,
    'left': -img.clientWidth * hide,
    'height': img.clientHeight,
});
```

Comment: I like this, it works, but I have a problem: if I have 59.7 as a value, I can get a width of 1253.7px; that doesn't break nicely on the webpage!

Comment: You could round it, or even floor it (`Math.round()` or `Math.floor()` if you're doing this in JS).

Comment: No, I mean I get a div of 1253.7px in this case, which just overflows over the border of the surrounding div...the result can get to even more (e.g. 78.3), which then gives me a div with a huuuuge width which doesn't fit on the screen

Comment: thank you, your solution certainly works, but I was hoping there would be something easier with jquery (like setting the width on  the img tag for only the fraction one), because on the same page I have several visualizations with different icons with different widths, so that would mean for every visualization a different calculation. Thinking about it, maybe yours is the only viable way :)

Comment: Hmm, if width of image varies, I can put another approach... :D

Comment: There it is, I hope a final version :D